# How to remove the tell me what you want to do search box in Ms Office Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is it possible to remove the annoying search bar in Excel 2016?

[image]

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: @CharlieRB I've spent about 20 minutes on google and have been through all the options in the menu and Ribbon. Nothing's there. Found [one post on MSDN saying it's impossible to turn that off](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/46c658b0-a10a-4aca-af10-438393b073ca/remove-tell-me-what-you-want-to-do-search-box-from-ms-office-16-ribbon?forum=Office2016ITPro) but it's just a guess.

Comment: Also I found the [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) but I am unsure what that Control's name is...

Answer (score 9):

Everybody seems to love this search box, even though in a lot of windows it actually takes more space than the actual menus! Clippy's back with the vengeance! Quick (and not so quick) search of the interwebs revealed absolutely nothing. But! But there is a workaround/crutch of sorts. "Customize the ribbon", add a new tab after all the visible ones, rename it to "as many spaces as you can fit in there" and a dot, and voila - the annoying search box goes to the far right of the window. It does not disappear completely, but I'm working in Full HD right now and the box is just a few initial letters. Blends in nicely with the close/minimize/etc. Maybe you could replace the dot at the end of tab name with some completely non-printing character for even less visual clutter.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves "(lightbulb) Tell me..." which is not great :( Very annoying

Answer (score 1):

In your Ribbon XML include the line:

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="True">
```

Insert this as the first line after the namespace line:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
```

I did this for another reason, but lo! the annoying (and dangerous) box disappeared!!!

Comment: Is this related to editing the ribbon of a single document as described [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/document-level-notepad.htm)? Or is there a way to edit a ribbon file that applies to all files?